# When does a potential function with given partial derivatives exist

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, integration

I am looking for the answer to the following question:

Consider an integrable function $f:X\rightarrow X$ with $X$ being a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. What are the conditions on $f$ so that a potential function $u:X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ exists so that $\nabla u(x) = f$ in $X$.

Obviously a necessary and sufficient condition is that for any closed path $r:[0,1]\rightarrow X$, we must have $\int f(x) dr =0$. The question is can this be further relaxed; perhaps under some assumption about $f$?

Comment: If a condition is both necessary and sufficient, how can there be any leeway to relax it?

Comment: For a general compact set $X$ it is not even clear what $\nabla u=f$ precisely means. There are several possibilities to define differentiability for functions on closed sets. In any case, necessity of $\int f(x)dr=0$ for closed (rectifiable) curves in $X$ should be clear but for general compact sets, I doubt that this is sufficient -- but this may depend on the notion of differentiability.

Comment: @MichaelEngelhardt Why not? For example, it could be sufficient to assume $\int f(x)dr=0$ only for very nice curves.

Comment: @JochenWengenroth - well, but that would contradict the OP's assertion that it is necessary to demand $\int f(x) dr=0$ for all curves. Mine was a meta-comment on the meaning of "necessary and sufficient" - I didn't mean any implication on the substance, where actually the OP's premise is probably incorrect under many circumstances, and you are right that it is not necessary to demand what the OP states.